# logrotate compression parameters

Tags: linux, unix, logrotate, resources

I've been using `cstream` for a while for many things, for example to reduce the impact that `mysqldump` has on drives. However, I have always done so by calling the binary directly from a script or cronjob.

I've got one situation now in which it would be great if I could use `cstream` from `logrotate`, but after some trials, I can't get it working.

You can use `cstream` in two different ways:

- as a "cat" binary

  `cstream foo | gzip`
- as a pipe from another process

  `mysqldump foo | cstream > dump.sql`

More precisely, I would like to call `cstream` from the `compresscmd` option.

Right now I just use this in `logrotate` config files.

```
compresscmd /bin/gzip
compressoptions -9
```

but like I said, I would like to use something like

```
compresscmd cstream foo | gzip
```

Is that possible? Can I use variables/macros from within `logrotate` config files so that I can pass the info of the file to compress to `cstream`?

Also, I tried to use `compresscmd` with a shell script to print the arguments that the script receives, but I only saw one argument with value=-9

So, actually I don't know how `gzip` picks up that info. Is it from some bash env value only available from `logrotate`?

I've had a look at `logrotate`'s documentation, but I can't see any answer to my doubts.

Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like logrotate is piping to the compresscmd, so you'll need to write a script which can handle the pipe. I'm sure perl / python could provide a more elegant solution, but here is what I was able to cobble together in bash:

with

```
compresscmd /root/mycompress.bash
```

mycompress.bash:

```
   #!/bin/bash

   ## set the field separator to NULL
   IFS=''

   ## read the pipe into an array
   ARRAY=()
   while read LINE
   do
       ARRAY+=($LINE)
   done

   ## echo the array and pipe to desired commands
   for item in ${ARRAY[*]}
   do
       echo $item
   done | cstream | gzip -9
```

**update:**

Upon reflection, the use of an array for temporary storage is unnecessary, so the above code can be reduced to:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    ## set the field separator to NULL
    IFS=''

    while read LINE
    do
            echo $LINE
    done | cstream
```

upon further reflection, because cstream handles pipes just fine on its own, mycompress.bash can be reduced to:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cstream | gzip
```